# Beamer - too much text one one slide

Tags: beamer

I'm making a beamer presentation with lots of text in itemize. How to tell latex to move the text to next slide, if the text does not fit the current one? (of course, without creating a new slide)

Also, the apparent "duplicate" is about tables, and the answer did not help.

Comment: You should use the option `allowframebreaks` inside your frame, it could help you:

    `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]`
    `Contents of the frame`
    `\end{frame}`

Comment: [Allowframebrakes] doesn't work. It shows first item of itemize on first slide, nest on on another one, and skips other. It's riddiculous that beamer itself cannot move the text to another slide. Every text editor can do that!

Comment: You should rethink your presentation design. To much text is unreadable for users in the back of the room. What about this: Split your bullet list - one point per slide? Slides in beamer presentations are for free! Otherwise a presentation is maybe not the right tool to present your data - use an article instead. AND: you don't have to write every word on a slide; say the words in your talk (that is why you're actually there). For further information give handouts to your listeners.

Comment: You DO realize it's not helpful in any matter, right? For god's sake, don't you think I know things you are trying to teach me? I'm asking why such a simple thing that works perfectly well in articles suddenly doesn't work in presentation. What if my presentation isn't for 5-year olds with a mental capacity and attention span of a goldfish, as you've seen to assume? Also, If the asker states it's not a duplicate, don't mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: Because the author pretty much designed the whole `beamer` to avoid such presentation style and promotes *designing each slide individually*. You can read the manual there is a huge section about why this is a bad idea. Hence, the mechanism for that is absent in the line of such view.

Comment: @user19502 Please bear in mind that everyone really is trying to help here, and keep that in mind in the tone of comments. (This applies to everyone, of course.) Your request is pretty unusual, and as TeX is about 'good quality' content it's not surprising to see comments trying to steer people toward alternative approaches.